# How to reverse a queue recursively?

Tags: c++, recursion, queue

I have the following class template and I wish to implement the reverse() function recursively without using any external/additional data structures.

```
template <class T> struct Node {
T value; Node<T> ∗next;
};
template <class T> class Dynque
{
protected :
 Node<T> ∗front;
 Node<T> ∗rear;
int numItems ; public :
Dynque();
Dynque ( Dynque & ) ;
virtual  ̃Dynque ( ) ;
virtual void enqueue (T) ; // add an element
T dequeue();// remove an element from front
bool isEmpty ( ) ;
int getNumItems ( ) ;
void clear (); // remove all elements
void reverse(); // reverse order of elements
};
```

Comment: What *language* is this written in? Can you please update the question with the relevant language tags?

Comment: There is an explanation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYH83T4q6Vs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be useful to think about, conceptually, how you'd reverse a queue recursively.

As with all good recursive functions, you'll need a base case, and the simpler, the better! A reasonable choice here is to pick the empty queue. Reversing the empty queue is easy - you get back exactly what you started with. So we could start off writing this function like this:

```
template <typename T> void Dynque<T>::reverse() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        /* ... handle the recursive case ... */
    }
}
```

Now we have to think about the recursive case. Imagine that we have a nonempty queue, and for simplicity, let's imagine the elements are numbered 1, 2, 3, ..., n, like this:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   ...   n-2  n-1  n
```

When working with queues, we only have access to the element at the front. So let's imagine that we split this queue into two groups: the first element, and everything else:

```
  |
1 | 2   3   4   5   6   ...   n-2  n-1  n
  |
```

Now, watch what we end up with when we reverse the queue:

```
                                    |
n  n-1  n-2  ...  6   5   4   3   2 | 1
                                    |
```

Notice that what we have here is the reverse of all the elements in the queue except the first, followed by the first element of the queue.

This leads to a nifty little insight. If we dequeue from the front of the queue, we're left with "everything else." If we then reverse "everything else," we can then enqueue the element that we removed, and we have the reverse of the original queue. Here's what this might look like:

```
template <typename T> void Dynque<T>::reverse() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        T first = dequeue(); // Store the first element...
        reverse();           // ... reverse everything else ...
        enqueue(first);      // ... and enqueue the element we removed.
    }
}
```

It's weird to see a recursive function that has no arguments, since the recursive action is happening as a result of the changes to the state of the queue that are happening via the enqueue and dequeue operations.

If you're curious why this works, think about what happens if you try to reverse the queue `[1, 2, 3]`. The logic looks like this:

```
 To reverse `[1, 2, 3]`, we dequeue 1, then recursively reverse `[2, 3].
   To reverse `[2, 3]`, we dequeue 2, then recursively reverse `[3]`.
       To reverse `[3]`, we dequeue 3, then recursively `[]`.
           To reverse `[]`, we don't need to do anything!
       Now we enqueue the 3 we removed to get `[3]`.
   Now we enqueue the 2 we removed to get `[3, 2]`.
Now we enqueue the 1 we removed to get `[3, 2, 1]`.
```

As a note, this is not a very efficient way to reverse a queue. It uses a ton of stack space to hold all of the elements removed at each step. You'd be better off using an explicit `std::stack` object or something like that to do the reversal (if you were implementing the reversal as a free function) or taking advantage of the fact that you can manually rewire pointers internally to rearrange everything. You could try optimizing this solution a bit, but doing so is far less worthwhile than just picking a fundamentally different solution strategy.

Answer (score 0):

```
Node reverse(Node front)
{
 if(front==NULL)
   return NULL;
 if(front->next==null)
   return front;
 Node rev=reverse(front->next);
 front->next->next=front;
 front->next=null;
 return rev; 

}
```

It should work like reversing a linkedlist. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the return type or  the reverse() functions parameters.  :(

Comment: If recursion has to be used, then parameter should be passed to your function so the stack can keep track of the value of Node at each stage. If you cannot change the signature of the reverse function, maybe you could try to call another function that reverses the queue and returns the head of the list to the reverse() function.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this (not tested):

```
void reverse() {
    // Base case
    if (isEmpty()) return;

    // Get head
    T head = dequeue();
    // Reverse everything else
    reverse();
    // Add head after reversion of everything else
    enqueue(head);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both enqueue() and dequeue() operate on values, they create **copies**. You really don't want to use these methods. You aren't adding or removing the data, it is only moved around, so let's do just that.

```
void Dynque::reverse()
{
    // No effect on 0 or 1 elements' count.
    if (isEmpty() || !front->next)
        return;

    // Remember the element at the front by keeping a pointer to it.
    Node<T>* move_me_to_back = front;

    // "Erase" the first element.
    front = front->next;

    // Call again on now shortened queue. 
    // In the most nested call, the queue should have only one element, with front == back.
    reverse();

    // "Insert" the last remembered element.
    back->next = move_me_to_back;

    // Update the pointer to back.
    back = back->next;
}
```